# How do I clear Android caches via ADB (Bricked phone)?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, boot-loop

I have used my phone and all was fine, but I wanted to reboot it and something went wrong. first it has stuck in boot loop, I waited ~10 minutes and thought it'll boot but no, then I tried enter a Recovery (twrp) and it just doesn't want to boot even in recovery. So I went to fastboot and flashed a new version of twrp, but it still won't boot. All the times when I have been stuck in a bootloop I just cleared caches via twrp and phone booted fine but now I really don`t know what I can do to rescue it and not lose my data. So maybe there is a way I can wipe caches without accessing the recovery menu? =(

If I force bootloader to load from fastboot it throws me back into a fastboot.

- Poco x3 nfc (surya)
- Android 12 Pixel Experience (official from their website)

Comment: so i have tried alot of recoveries ( bunch of twrps, 3 orange foxes, PE recovery) no one works, TWRP&OF just hangs on splash screens and PErecovery is just a black screen. i just have no clue what do i do. i can try flash rom from a fastboot but then i will lose all my data. that sucks

Comment: Instead of adding info using comments please edit your question instead.